# enabling cpp header file checking with syntastic in vim

Tags: c++, vim, syntastic

I just started using syntastic for vim, and I'm loving it so far, but I have one tiny issue.  If the file extension is not cpp, running ":SyntasticCheck" does absolutely nothing.  This is a problem, as I would like to run syntastic on header files as well, with extensions such as ".h" or ".hpp".  Can anyone help me out?  I'm using 'gcc' as my cpp syntastic-checker, if that helps.

Comment: figured it out

add this to your vimrc to enable header file checking with gcc syntastic checker:
let g:syntastic_cpp_check_header = 1

Comment: If that solved your problem. post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to your vimrc

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_check_header = 1
```

this setting was found by reading the comment at the top of `<syntastic>/syntax_checker/cpp/gcc.vim`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to add the path contains your header files such as
`let g:syntastic_c_include_dirs = ['../../include','../include','include']`
and turn on the variable to check your header files
`let g:syntastic_c_check_header = 1`

Moreover, you can also pass flags and options to compiler by 
`let b:syntastic_c_cflags = '-I/usr/include/libsoup-2.4'`
 and `let g:syntastic_c_compiler_options = '-ansi -DMACRO_NAME'`.

It helps in many conditions i.e. when you have many macro definitions.

You can find more useful options in its official Github.
[C:gcc checker options](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/C%3a---gcc)